# PHP password_verify with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a little trouble with a login script. You can probably tell im pretty new to this. I have troubleshooted the problem to being in the if(password_verify) statement! All help is appreciated, and please critique anything if noticed!

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
require '../../usersTable.php';
$stmt_check = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt_check->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt_check->execute();
if ($stmt_check->num_rows > 0) {
    if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        $conn->close();
        // Success!
        header('Location: ../')
    } else {
        $conn->close();
        // Invalid credentials
        echo 'Password Mismatch';
    }
} else {
    $conn->close();
    echo "incorrect Email!";
}
```

Comment: Check that your `$row['password']` isn't a copy+paste error; it looks like you don't declare `$row` anywhere.

Comment: You are missing `;` after `header('Location: ../')`. This will give you a syntax error.

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');`

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to add one line before your `if(password_verify...` line

```
$row = $stmt_check->get_result()->fetch_array();
if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
    // ...
```

This will get a single row from your DB result.